# Помогите с ответом

Tags: языкознание

Какая разница между языковой личностью и диалектоносителем?

Answer (score 1):

По большому счету никакой.Некорректное сравнение-какая разница между одетым человеком и человеком в спортивном костюме?Диалект это одна из составляющих языка, мы все носители далектов.